# Há como remover do CSS e JS códigos não utilizados pela aplicação?

Tags: html, css, minificação

Gostaria de saber se existe algum *transpilador* que analisa as classes e *ids* usados numa pagina HTML e retira todas as classes e *ids* não utilizados no CSS e JavaScript.

Isso seria interessante para diminuir ainda mais os arquivos melhorando o desempenho das páginas.

Comment: Tipo o [Tree Shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/)?

Comment: Vc quer algo automático para grandes volumes, ou pode ser uma resposta com uma solução mais simples que te ajude a fazer isso de forma "manual" e em pequena escala?

Comment: Eu gostaria de saber um pouco sobre os dois

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Como vc falou que uma solução em "pequena escala" também te atende, vou te dar uma dica usando a **Aba Coverage** do `DevTools` do Chrome. Link do Google https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/devtools-release-notes#coverage

Na **Aba Coverage** vc consegue avaliar o que do código realmente está em uso, vale tanto pra CSS quanto para JS. Deixei os comentários na imagem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O detalhe é que por exemplo o CSS responsivo só é marcado como Verde quando ele realmente é ativado. Esse é o único inconveniente dessa técnica, pq vc tem que navegar pela página para ver o que é usado ou não. Repare que como falei não existe `<h1>` no HTML, então a regra CSS do `<h1>` nunca vai ficar Verde

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Veja essa outra imagem com um documento maior!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Como falei não é a solução perfeita para grandes projetos, mas se for usado desde o início e fazendo as auditorias direitinho em curtos períodos de tempo e possível controlar bem o que se está de fato usando e o que é "lixo"...

---

**EDIT Como abrir a ABA COVERAGE**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**Extensão para o Chrome**

No **Chrome Web Store** vc também encontra algumas extensões que ajudam nisso https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/code-coverage-calculator/ncdifkcipeniikkbckejmnbbcofdheig

---

**Automatizando com PurgeCSS**

Vc pode usar ferramentas como o PurgeCSS https://www.purgecss.com/ para eliminar código CSS que não está utilizando, vc precisa ter Node instalado. Basicamente ele vai ler seu HTML comparar com o CSS e soltar um .css purificado só com o de fato vc está usando. O legal é que vc pode configura-lo para rodar com Ruby, ou em compiladores como Gulp e Grunt ou no Webpack. Ai sempre que compilar ele já faz o purge. Aqui tem o projeto no Git https://github.com/FullHuman/purgecss

Comment: Qual versão do Crome isso está disponível?

Comment: @Marconi conforme o link a partir da **versão 59** tem que dar um F5 depois que abrir a aba https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/devtools-release-notes#coverage Editei a resposta mostrando como abre essa Aba no DevTools

Comment: No que tange a ativação da propriedade `@media`, pode colocar a tela no modo responsivo para vários dispositivos.